# How to set EditIndex property of the GridView to "Selected Row" in the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have put a gridview on my webform, linked it to sql-database. I have put Edit button on the GridView for users to edit records.

When a user clicks Edit button, I need to set `EditIndex` property of the Grid to that `SelectedRow` index. Please help me write it's code.

Comment: My experience with ASP.NET is pretty limited but isn't this just a question of doing something like `GridView1.EditIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;` in the Click-event for the button?

Comment: StackOverflow is not that type of site. You should be writing the code yourself as far as you are able, then coming back here with any problems you encounter.

Answer (score 3):

Code something like this

On edit click Gridview  will be editable , gvBind() is method for binding your gridview with datatable

```
 protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
       gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gvBind();
    }

 protected void gv_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gv.EditIndex = -1;
        gvBind();
    }
```